# Opinions vs statistics: Polls?

Tags: discussion

So, yesterday someone from my chess club claimed that he had problem with keeping the
overview of the real board - he was accustomed to online chess with "printed" boards.
Naturally, playing OTB since more than half a century I was surprised.

Can that be turned into a question?

"Are printed boards easier to overview than real ones?" Clearly opinionated.

"Are printed boards easier to overview than real ones for the majority of chess players?" That's a yes-or-no question, but you probably had to run a poll. [Whoopsie, we don't do polls on SE. For reasons.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279262/what-should-we-do-with-sets-of-answers-that-are-actually-polling-options)

Any suggestions for the curious SE user?

Comment: Why don't you specify in the question that you are seeking credible statistics reporting? If someone was foolish enough to think their personal opinion is responsive to a request for independent facts, downvote and flag it. Or ask for a comparison of accessibility issues between real boards/pieces and flat/printed/screen displays, UX is reasonably well-founded in most areas.